# Not sure how to do ajax functions inside of Javascript to get to mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, timertask

I'm not quite sure how to go about putting an ajax function inside of my Javascript timer so that every time it restarts then it'll add one of the item into the database. I've been looking and I found this: http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ajax-mysql-database.php but I'm not quite sure how to implement it into the code, so if you could help me it'd be appreciated.

Here's my code so far:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var c=10;
var mineCount = 0;
var t;
var timer_is_on=0;

function timedCount() {
document.getElementById('txt').value = c;
c = c - 1;
if (c <= -1) {
mineCount++;
var _message = "You have mined " + mineCount + " iron ore" + (((mineCount > 1) ? "s" : "") + "!");
document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = _message;
startover();
}
}

function startover() {
 c = 10;
clearTimeout(t);
timer_is_on=0;
doMining();
}
function doMining() {
if (!timer_is_on) {
    timer_is_on = true;
    t = setInterval(function () {
        timedCount();
    }, 1000);                
}
}

</script> 

<SPAN STYLE="float:left">
<form>
<input type="button" value="Mining" onClick="doMining()">
<input type="text" id="txt">
</form>
</SPAN>
<html>
<center>
<div id='message'></div>
```

Comment: Do you know PHP? Might be handy to know to answer your Q.

Comment: Javascript is client side technology. What technology do you use for server side?

Comment: @Nitin the question has a link to a tutorial about JS, PHP and MySQL. 99% chance PHP is used.

Comment: yes i do know how to code in php, this is just a section of my game code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try including [jquery](http://jquery.com) and put `$.post('path/to/file.php', {param1: value1});` in your `doMining()` function

Comment: ok, my question is what file do i put in there? like would i use the one that connects to the mysql database and table? please explain a little if you will, please :D

Comment: The javascript will not update the database directly, but call a php script on your server. you need to put the code to connect to mysql and run the update query in a php script on your server. then, from javascript call that script as I wrote in the answer (you will replace path/to/file.php with the url of your php file).

Answer (score 0):

Idea of AJAX is, we will send sync/async request to server from the client side by using any scripting language like Javascript, and in server side processing we will do the desired functionality and send response as required.

I am not sure about PHP, as i generally work in dotnet. 
So in PHP i hope there would be some way to create a web service or to create a web page, in that Page or Service get the appropriate parameters by using query string or post and then call the desired functionality of updating the DB. Then you can write in response to send the response back to JS client. JS can parse the reponse and can update UI as required.

Some references:

[Using XmlHttp in Javascript](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/simple-ajax-php-and-javascript)

Comment: i was told that javascript cant talk directly to the server, so that ajax would be an intermediary to talk to the php script and the mysql database, but im not quite sure